# Porque no puedo crear un archivo txt en C?

Tags: c, archivo

No puedo crear archivo tanto en modo de apertura binario como de texto. No se si es que estoy haciendo algo mal en el código o es mi compilador. Por lo que tenía entendido si el archivo no existe y yo lo creo tendría que poder hacerse.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define ERROR 1
int main(){

FILE *pf;

pf = fopen("ArchivoTexto.txt","w");

if(pf == NULL)
  {
    printf("Error al crear el archivo");
    return ERROR;
  }
}
```

Comment: Acabo de probar este código y funcionó perfectamente. Cómo lo estás ejecutando?

Comment: Si tuvieras algún error, el mensaje debería mostrarse. Asegúrate de que estás viendo la carpeta donde se ejecuta el programa.

Answer (score 2):

Sacado de la [documentación](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fopen.htm):

> This function returns a FILE pointer. Otherwise, NULL is returned and the global variable errno is set to indicate the error.

Es decir, para saber qué está pasando podrías hacer algo tal que:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

if (pf == NULL)
{
    puts("Error al crear el archivo\n");
    puts(strerror(errno));
    return ERROR;
}
```